# Viewing images and links on click

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview, android-imageview, android-xml

I have two questions, each similar to each other.

**Firstly**, my app loads images from my web server. When a user clicks the image, I need it to open the image in some sort of image viewer (where you can zoom into the image and pan around). Can I also load galleries/albums of images?

I'm currently using the [Glide library](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to load the images into the `ImageView`, but how can I implement the image viewer when the user clicks the `ImageView`?

Also, is it possible to load a smaller (thumbnail) image into the `ImageView` using Glide, but open the full-sized image when the user clicks on it and opens it in the image viewer?

Here is my `ImageView`:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    />
```

Here is how I load the image into the `ImageView` using Glide:

```
Glide.with(context)
        .load("http://www.website.com/test.png")
        .fitCenter()
        .into(holder.imageView);
```

**Secondly**, my app has links to external websites that the user is able to click on. How can I open these links within the app, rather than opening it in a browser? Is there a library for this?

Comment: Open link in `WebView` with `Fragment` or `Activity`

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, use the onClick method. When clicking on an imageview, send the source for that image in a bundle to the next activity or fragment to be opened and show the full image there.

For the second question, open your links in a webview. The further clicks will be handled themselves